# How to build this layout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an **app** that has one page where it should be an `image` at the top and then a **table** underneath it. The thing is that when I scroll, I want everything to scroll, including the `image`. What is the best approach for this:

- a scrollview with an image view and a table view ?
- create some kind of static cell in the tableview for the image?

Does anyone know some examples?
Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: 1)Create a `tableview`. 2)Create two custom tableviewcells. 3) First cell's content view consist of image view. 4)Second cell's content view contains other elements as shown in your gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use a UITableViewController. With that you can implement all the cells easily and efficiency. Then drag and drop an imageView on top of the tableView in the UITableViewController. You can place it right between the tableView and the Top to get what you want.